# If an artist draws, what does a therapist do?

Tags: single-word-requests

I was thinking something along the lines of "console" or in that vein but it doesn't really roll off the tongue. Are there any other words that are more fitting?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135954/discussion-on-question-by-confused-therapist-if-an-artist-draws-what-does-a-the).

Comment: Are you looking for a word that would apply to both psychological care *and* physical therapy?

Comment: A therapist provides therapies.

Comment: A therapist provides therapy, or consults, or heals, or helps resolve issues, depends on the specific type of therapy.

Answer (score 1):

From Merriam-Webster, a therapist is "an individual specializing in the therapeutic medical treatment of impairment, injury, disease, or disorder". It follows that a therapist *treats*.